# How to use html radio button label with Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, radio-button, label

I was trying to display a list in html as label for radio button which should look like this:

---

|  option1  |

---

|  option2  |

---

The option number is not fixed,in my back-end, I use AngularJs to make the website dynamic. 
My code looks like this:

{{opt}}

Now the result I have looks like this:

---

|  option1  |
|  option2  |

---

I know it is because I only create a

but don't know how to fix it, could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question you are trying to get your label buttons to look like `list items`?

If so use this CSS to get the container of your radio boxes to look like `list items`:

```
.label {
  display: list-item;
}
```

Also I would like to point out that `Angular JS` is **NOT** a `back-end` framework.

> AngularJS is a structural (**front end**) framework for dynamic web apps. It lets you use HTML as your template language and lets you extend HTML's syntax to express your application's components clearly and succinctly.
>   ([Source](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction))

You can read more about what Angular JS is over [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/introduction).
You can also read more about Angular's Api over [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api).

Good luck and all the best.